# Partition tables esp32 3mb no ota 1mb spiffs Platform io

Tags: esp32, platformio, guid-partition-table

I'm using esp32 whroom with platform io .
my question is how do i set the the partition table to 3MB no OTA and 1MB to Spiffs i understand i need to use configuretion code in the platformio.ini file but couldn't find a good guide online  , thank for answers

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own partition table as descriped in the docs of [PlatformIO](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/platforms/espressif32.html#partition-tables).

You can find a lot of examples and predefined partition tables [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/tools/partitions).

If you want to get a deeper insight, have a look at the docs of [Espressif](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html).